# Why my Ajax events are no longer detected after dynamic change of shortcode content

Tags: php, shortcode, ajax

I have two `input select` (dropdown) in the content of my shortcode. The first is created when initializing the shortcode content, while the second is created when the user chooses the value of the first dropdown. For this purpose, the second one is created dynamically with an Ajax handle. 
The choice of the second entry must display some corresponding data.

The first dropdown works well: it displays the second dropdown with its values. 
The problem occurs when I want to choose the value of the second dropdown. I use the same jQuery event (`element.on('change' ...`) and it never goes off. It's exactly the same as the first one, but it doesn't work. 
Could someone please explain to me why?

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php 
/**
 *   Plugin Name: demoConnecteurs
 *   Description: Plugin de démo des connecteurs Jenkins et Mantis
**/
require_once(file_with_external_fonctions.php);

$inst_demo = new demo();
if (isset($inst_demo)){
}

class demo{   
    private $dataFirstDropdown;
    private $dataSecondDropdown;
    private $dataDependingSecondDropdown;


    function __construct(){
        $this->setDataFirstDropdown();

        $this->initAjaxActions();

        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'demo_scripts'));
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'demo_scripts'));


        $this->init();
    }

    function initAjaxActions(){
        add_action('wp_ajax_setChoiceFirstDropdown', array($this,'setChoiceFirstDropdown'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_setChoiceFirstDropdown', array($this,'setChoiceFirstDropdown'));        
        add_action('wp_ajax_setChoiceSecondDropdown', array($this,'setChoiceSecondDropdown'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_setChoiceSecondDropdown', array($this,'setChoiceSecondDropdown'));
    }

    function demo_scripts(){
        wp_register_script( 'ajaxHandle', plugins_url() . '/DemoConnecteurs/buttons_ajax.js');
        wp_localize_script( 'ajaxHandle', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxHandle');
    }

    function init(){
        add_shortcode( 'demo', array($this,'demo_shortcode') );
    }

    function demo_shortcode () {
        return $this->contentCore();
    }

    public function setDataFirstDropdown(){
        $this->dataFirstDropdown = getDataFirstDropdown(); //external function
    }

   public function setDataSecondDropdown(){
        $this->dataSecondDropdown = getDataSecondDropdown($this->dataFirstDropdown); //external function
    }

   public function setDataDependingSecondDropdown(){
        $this->dataResultsOfSecondDropdown = getDataDependingSecondDropdown($this->dataSecondDropdown);
    }

    public function setChoiceFirstDropdown(){
        if (isset ($_POST['demo_data_first_dropdown']))$this->dataFirstDropdown = $_POST['demo_data_first_dropdown'];

        $this->setDataSecondDropdown();
        echo $this->contentSecondDropdown();
        wp_die();
    }

    public function setChoiceSecondDropdown(){
        if (isset ($_POST['demo_data_second_dropdown']))$this->dataDependingSecondDropdown = $_POST['demo_data_second_dropdown'];

        $this->setDataDependingSecondDropdown();
        echo $this->contentDependingSecondDropdown();
        wp_die();
    }

    function contentCore(){
        $html = "";

        $html .= '<div id="firstDropdown" : ';        
        $html .= '<select id="selectFirstDropdown">';
        foreach($this->dataFirstDropdown as $f) {
           //working
        }
        $html .= '</select></div>';

        $html .= '<div id="secondDropdown"></div>';

        $html .= '<div id="dependingSecondDropdown"></div>';

        return $html;
    }

    public function contentSecondDropdown(){
        $html = '<select id="selectSecondDropdown">';
        foreach($this->dataSecondDropdown as $s) {
           //working
        }
        $html .= '</select></div>';
        return $html;
    }

    public function contentDependingSecondDropdown(){
        $this->dataDependingSecondDropdown;
        return $html;
    }
}
```

and here my jQuery functions with ajax handlers:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#firstDropdown').on('change', function (e) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action': 'setChoiceFirstDropdown',
                'demo_projet_name': $('#firstDropdown option:selected').val()
            },
            success: function (output) {
                $('#secondDropdown').html(output);
            }
        });
    } );

    $('#secondDropdown').on('change', function (e) {
        console.log('not logged...');
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action': 'setChoiceSecondDropdown',
                'demo_version_id': $('#secondDropdown option:selected').val()
            },
            success: function (output) {
                console.log(output);
                $('#dependingSecondDropdown').html(output);
            }
        });
    } );    
} );
```

Comment: None of your action or function names match. On `#firstDropdown` the action you're sending is `setChoiceFirstDropdown`, but there's no hook for `wp_ajax_setChoiceFirstDropdown`. You _have_ hooked `wp_ajax_actionFirstDropdown`, but then the callback function for it is `array($this,'actionFirstDropdown')`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: you're right, I made a mistake while copy/paste and change the name of my variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to do the right ajax actions... 
For the second dropdown, I had to first detect the click on the statically created div then detect the change on the dynamically created dropdown.

Here the correct code:

```
<?php 
/**
 *   Plugin Name: demoConnecteurs
 *   Description: Plugin de démo des connecteurs Jenkins et Mantis
**/
require_once(file_with_external_fonctions.php);

$inst_demo = new demo();
if (isset($inst_demo)){
}

class demo{   
    private $dataFirstDropdown;
    private $dataSecondDropdown;
    private $dataDependingSecondDropdown;


    function __construct(){
        $this->setDataFirstDropdown();

        $this->initAjaxActions();

        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'demo_scripts'));
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'demo_scripts'));


        $this->init();
    }

    function initAjaxActions(){
        add_action('wp_ajax_setChoiceFirstDropdown', array($this,'setChoiceFirstDropdown'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_setChoiceFirstDropdown', array($this,'setChoiceFirstDropdown'));        
        add_action('wp_ajax_setChoiceSecondDropdown', array($this,'setChoiceSecondDropdown'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_setChoiceSecondDropdown', array($this,'setChoiceSecondDropdown'));
    }

    function demo_scripts(){
        wp_register_script( 'ajaxHandle', plugins_url() . '/DemoConnecteurs/buttons_ajax.js');
        wp_localize_script( 'ajaxHandle', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxHandle');
    }

    function init(){
        add_shortcode( 'demo', array($this,'demo_shortcode') );
    }

    function demo_shortcode () {
        return $this->contentCore();
    }

    public function setDataFirstDropdown(){
        $this->dataFirstDropdown = getDataFirstDropdown(); //external function
    }

   public function setDataSecondDropdown(){
        $this->dataSecondDropdown = getDataSecondDropdown($this->dataFirstDropdown); //external function
    }

   public function setDataDependingSecondDropdown(){
        $this->dataResultsOfSecondDropdown = getDataDependingSecondDropdown($this->dataSecondDropdown);
    }

    public function setChoiceFirstDropdown(){
        if (isset ($_POST['demo_data_first_dropdown']))$this->dataFirstDropdown = $_POST['demo_data_first_dropdown'];

        $this->setDataSecondDropdown();
        echo $this->contentSecondDropdown();
        wp_die();
    }

    public function setChoiceSecondDropdown(){
        if (isset ($_POST['demo_data_second_dropdown']))$this->dataDependingSecondDropdown = $_POST['demo_data_second_dropdown'];

        $this->setDataDependingSecondDropdown();
        echo $this->contentDependingSecondDropdown();
        wp_die();
    }

    function contentCore(){
        $html = "";

        $html .= '<div id="firstDropdown" : ';        
        $html .= '<select id="selectFirstDropdown">';
        foreach($this->dataFirstDropdown as $f) {
           //working
        }
        $html .= '</select></div>';

        $html .= '<div id="secondDropdown"></div>';

        $html .= '<div id="dependingSecondDropdown"></div>';

        return $html;
    }

    public function contentSecondDropdown(){
        $html = '<select id="selectSecondDropdown">';
        foreach($this->dataSecondDropdown as $s) {
           //working
        }
        $html .= '</select></div>';
        return $html;
    }

    public function contentDependingSecondDropdown(){
        $this->dataDependingSecondDropdown;
        return $html;
    }
}
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#selectFirstDropdown').on('change', function (e) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action': 'setChoiceFirstDropdown',
                'demo_projet_name': $('#firstDropdown option:selected').val()
            },
            success: function (output) {
                $('#secondDropdown').html(output);
            }
        });
    } );

    $('#secondDropdown').on('click', function (e) {
        $('#selectSecondDropdown').on('click', function (e) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    'action': 'setChoiceSecondDropdown',
                    'demo_version_id': $('#secondDropdown option:selected').val()
                },
                success: function (output) {
                    console.log(output);
                    $('#dependingSecondDropdown').html(output);
                }
            } );
        } );
    } );    
} );
```